# Handling HTTPS post request in python flask

Tags: python, flask, https

I have made a simple python flask program :

```
   # save this as app.py
from flask import request
from flask import Flask


    
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"
    
@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
def sms():
    print(request.get_json())
    return "sms world"
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=443, host='0.0.0.0', ssl_context='adhoc')
```

This handles the HTTP post request. How can I make it handle HTTPS post requests?

When I execute the command `flask run` I get the following:

> - Environment: production    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.    Use a production WSGI server
>   instead.  * Debug mode: off  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
>   (Press CTRL+C to quit)

So it still uses HTTP instead of https

Answer (score 0):

```
 pip install pyopenssl
```

When you run the script (or start with flask run if you prefer), you will notice that Flask indicates that it is running an https:// istance

Comment: That didn't work. Could it be because my python directory is set to `anaconda3/bin/python` . `pip install pyopenssl` shows requirement already satisfied

Comment: flask run showed the following `flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

Answer (score 0):

first install `pyopenssl` with the command:

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

to launch it in https just add the parameter: `ssl_context='adhoc'`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=443, host='0.0.0.0', ssl_context='adhoc')
```

Once started the following message will be shown:

```
* Serving Flask app 'test' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on all addresses.
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
* Running on https://192.168.0.62:443/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Obviously then once the application goes into production this parameter will no longer be needed, but you will have to set your wsgi to communicate in https

Comment: Doesn't work. I think I might have to add certificates and keys...I am not sure though...

Comment: If you installed pyopenssl as suggested by @
user16502050, it must work without any need to manually specify certificates. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I have updated the code in the OP. Just to show that for me it still shows HTTP instead of https. Not sure what could be the reason for this as it seems it's running fine at your side

Answer (score 0):

You can try ngrok, it is a useful tool to deploy an HTTPS and HTTP service from local to public net.

https://ngrok.com/